# SSH Rsync to a remote server through an intermediary server

Tags: ssh, rsync

I am on a linux server (server A), I can SSH to another linux server (server B). Once on server B, I can SSH to another linux server (Server C). So basically, Server A can not talk directly to Server C without going through Server B. Here's the problem: I need to rsync server A and C, initiated by a script on server A.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but you can create ssh tunnel to server C via server B (this command creates ssh tunnel in background, so you have to bother killing it after finishing rsyncing):

```
ssh -f -N -L 2222:<C>:22 <username>@<B>
```

and then just tell `rsync` to connect to `localhost:2222` instead of `<C>:22`.

Of course you can specify any other temporary port instead of 2222